# DB Error: database disk image is malformed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am running code from this tutorial [sqlite database iOS app tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) . But it is giving sql error on inserting record

> DB Error: database disk image is malformed...
>   Could not execute the query.

How do I fix that error?

Comment: Remove the DB file, and create a new one.

Comment: i have created new one but getting same error....

Comment: Use the sqlite3 command line tool to examine the file.  See what it says.  (But note that you need to examine the file in the location to which it's been copied during your startup procedure.)

Answer (score -1):

You should use this command:

yum clean dbcache

or

mv /var/lib/rpm/__db* /tmp
rpm --rebuilddb

Comment: The OP is describing an iOS app. There is no yum to run.