# no such table .. Could not execute the query... xcode sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am using code from [sqlite database iOS app tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/), but it is giving sql error when inserting a record:

```
2014-12-15 12:08:08.458 SQLite3DBSample[2677:60b] no such table: peopleInfo
2014-12-15 12:08:18.703 SQLite3DBSample[2677:60b] no such table: peopleInfo
2014-12-15 12:08:18.704 SQLite3DBSample[2677:60b] Could not execute the query.
```

Code in ViewController.h file is :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DBManager.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrPeopleInfo;

@property (nonatomic) int recordIDToEdit;


-(void)loadData;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Make self the delegate and datasource of the table view.
    self.tblPeople.delegate = self;
    self.tblPeople.dataSource = self;

    // Initialize the dbManager property.
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"sampledb.sql"];

    // Load the data.
    [self loadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    EditInfoViewController *editInfoViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    editInfoViewController.delegate = self;
    editInfoViewController.recordIDToEdit = self.recordIDToEdit;
}


#pragma mark - IBAction method implementation

- (IBAction)addNewRecord:(id)sender {
    // Before performing the segue, set the -1 value to the recordIDToEdit. That way we'll indicate that we want to add a new record and not to edit an existing one.
    self.recordIDToEdit = -1;

    // Perform the segue.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueEditInfo" sender:self];
}


#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)loadData{
    // Form the query.
    NSString *query = @"select * from peopleInfo";

    // Get the results.
    if (self.arrPeopleInfo != nil) {
        self.arrPeopleInfo = nil;
    }
    self.arrPeopleInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tblPeople reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - UITableView method implementation

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.arrPeopleInfo.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Dequeue the cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellRecord" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger indexOfFirstname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"];
    NSInteger indexOfLastname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"];
    NSInteger indexOfAge = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"age"];

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfLastname]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Age: %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfAge]];

    return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 60.0;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Get the record ID of the selected name and set it to the recordIDToEdit property.
    self.recordIDToEdit = [[[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

    // Perform the segue.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueEditInfo" sender:self];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the selected record.
        // Find the record ID.
        int recordIDToDelete = [[[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

        // Prepare the query.
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from peopleInfo where peopleInfoID=%d", recordIDToDelete];

        // Execute the query.
        [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

        // Reload the table view.
        [self loadData];
    }
}


#pragma mark - EditInfoViewControllerDelegate method implementation

-(void)editingInfoWasFinished{
    // Reload the data.
    [self loadData];
}


@end
```

Code in EditInfoViewController.h is :

```
#import "EditInfoViewController.h"
#import "DBManager.h"


@interface EditInfoViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;

-(void)loadInfoToEdit;

@end


@implementation EditInfoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Make self the delegate of the textfields.
    self.txtFirstname.delegate = self;
    self.txtLastname.delegate = self;
    self.txtAge.delegate = self;

    // Set the navigation bar tint color.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor;

    // Initialize the dbManager object.
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"sampledb.sql"];

    // Check if should load specific record for editing.
    if (self.recordIDToEdit != -1) {
        // Load the record with the specific ID from the database.
        [self loadInfoToEdit];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate method implementation

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - IBAction method implementation

- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    // Prepare the query string.
    // If the recordIDToEdit property has value other than -1, then create an update query. Otherwise create an insert query.
    NSString *query;
    if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', '%@', %d)", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, [self.txtAge.text intValue]];
    }
    else{
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', lastname='%@', age=%d where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, self.txtAge.text.intValue, self.recordIDToEdit];
    }


    // Execute the query.
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

    // If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.
    if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

        // Inform the delegate that the editing was finished.
        [self.delegate editingInfoWasFinished];

        // Pop the view controller.
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
    }
}


#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)loadInfoToEdit{
    // Create the query.
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where peopleInfoID=%d", self.recordIDToEdit];

    // Load the relevant data.
    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

    // Set the loaded data to the textfields.
    self.txtFirstname.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"]];
    self.txtLastname.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"]];
    self.txtAge.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"age"]];
}


@end
```

Even if I remove the database file, and create a new database it gives the same error. How to fix those errors? Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any table with that name in your db file ?

Comment: db file means database file

Comment: Yes, in your database file.

Comment: database name is:sampledb.sql ... table name is: peopleInfo

Comment: send me complete query..

Comment: download code form this link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/SQLite3DBSample.zip

Comment: Is this question solved? I am on the same boat as you, no such table: peopleInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your query is executing without any issues. Your message comes wrong due to the following code:

```
BOOL executeQueryResults = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
 if (executeQueryResults == SQLITE_DONE)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Change that to:

```
 if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
 {
    ...
 }
```

`SQLITE_DONE` is a macro, defined with with value 101, you are trying to compare that with a BOOL, so the condition is failing each time.

Comment: still not working...giving the same error...previous problems in this project was this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456053/db-error-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Comment: @frincit I just downloaded the code, you put on the Dropbox and I made the change. It's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

load your table in viewdidAppear like that

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
[self loadData]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by "reseting content and setting" of simulator but please make sure your code is correct and table really exists in database first. You can use "sqlite browser" to check database and its tables. You can download "sqlite browser" from this link -> http://sqlitebrowser.org/

For more information, please refer this link -> [sqlite prepare statement error - no such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656894/sqlite-prepare-statement-error-no-such-table)

[image]